# radiobutton does not reference in Form1 (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

I have a radio button called `radiobutton1`. I wrote the code below in `Form1.cs` after creating the button from toolbox in `Form1.cs[design]`:

```
private void radiobutton1_checkchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flag object = 2;
    flag_P = 0;
    n_objA = int.parse(objD_n.text);
}
```

However on top of `private void` it says, 0 references. When I double-click `radiobutton1` in `Form1.cs[design]`, the following code emerges in `Form1.cs`:

```
private void radiobutton1_checkchanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The text above `private void` states that this has 1 reference.

How come the code I wrote has no reference and how do I connect this code to the radio button?

Comment: Don't you have to bind your methods to the corresponding event? Try doing a solution wide search for `button1_checkchanged_1`.

Comment: are you really sure it is 'radio **space** button1_checkchanged' ? i think you should remove the space ...

Comment: My apologies. There wasn`t a space.

Comment: You corrected it, nice. Did you tried to clean and rebuild your solution?

Comment: Yes, its working fine now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your radio button in design mode
2. see the property window
3. click the event button
4. that's it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Designer view**, select **Properties** of your `radiobutton1`, then select **`Events`** tab:

Actually you have created 2 events for `CheckedChanged`. Now from the dropdown list simply select the `button1_checkchanged` and it will be subscribed:

[image]